# How to regain control over a Samsung Galaxy S II with a Boot loop?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, boot-loop

My device is in a wicked boot loop and I cannot get any control over the phone.

If I take the battery out and put it back in, it just restarts again and again. I don't feel like I have any control over the buttons on the phone.

Any way to solve this?
I'm completely willing to restore factory settings, but I just don't know how I could do so because the phone does not shut off, it just continues to restart.

Comment: Does it immediately switch on as soon as you put the battery back in, even if you left the battery out for several minutes? You can find a few ways to factory-reset your S2 on [hard-reset.com](http://www.hard-reset.com/samsung-galaxy-s-ii-hard-reset.html?ModPagespeed=noscript).

Answer (score 1):

Enter recovery mode and do a factory reset and wipe cache and install any ROM you like.

It worked for my S2 which got stuck during boot-up. I kept flashing my ROM without factory reset and wipe cache and nothing happened.

It went back to normal when I did those procedure above. Hope it will solve your problem. My S2 is fine and running again. <sub>I almost gave up on it.</sub>